# Laravel activity log does not update properties column

Tags: laravel-7, activitylog

I am learning to log an activity in Laravel(7.1) using `spatie/laravel-activitylog` package. But when I update an user, it does not update `properties` column in `activity_log` table, I set `$logAttributes`  attribute on model (`protected static $logAttributes = ['name', 'email'];`)

When I update an user like

```
>>> $user = User::find(1);

=> App\User {#3104
     id: 1,
     name: "John",
     email: "prath@example.com",
     email_verified_at: "2020-03-12 13:35:19",
     created_at: "2020-03-12 13:35:19",
     updated_at: "2020-03-12 13:41:34",
   }
>>> $user->update(['name' => 'James']);
=> true
```

and it logs that activity but returns with an empty properties column.

```
{
id: 8,
log_name: "default",
description: "updated",
subject_id: 1,
subject_type: "App\User",
causer_id: null,
causer_type: null,
properties: [ ],
created_at: "2020-03-12T14:58:10.000000Z",
updated_at: "2020-03-12T14:58:10.000000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your model add these field name which you want to update:

```
protected static $logAttributes = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'];
protected static $logOnlyDirty = true;

php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

do this for each log activity update, since all log activities are cached
**php artisan config:clear**